# What does a HTTP Request that references a file in the middle of the path?

Tags: php, http, cgi, webserver

I'm writting a HTTP server and when i tried the Serendipity PHP Blog i get requests from the browser like this one:

GET /serendipity_admin.php/templates/default/admin/pluginmanager.css HTTP/1.1

The "/serendipity_admin.php" file does exist so the 
"/serendipity_admin.php/templates/default/admin/pluginmanager.css" obviously must fail.

What should a webserver do when it discounters such a request?

I tried to just execute "/serendipity_admin.php" with the usual HTTP request headers (REQUEST_URI, PATH_INFO etc), but this does not seem to work so there is some more magick required. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the web server will try to match the url from left to right.

since it finds the .php file, it will call it ,  the rest of the url will then be stored in the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] global PHP variable that is available for reading by the script.

Then the script can perform its logic depending on this variable.

Answer (score 1):

`REQUEST_URI` and `PATH_INFO` are not HTTP request headers.  They are CGI environment variables.

A request for `/serendipity_admin.php/templates/default/admin/pluginmanager.css` results in `/serendipity_admin.php` being run with `PATH_INFO` as `/templates/default/admin/pluginmanager.css`

You should [read the CGI specification](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/interface.html).

Answer (score 0):

The blog probably excepts that you are running a module that works like Apache's MultiView. Multiview causes Apache to look for `serendipity_admin.php` (among other things) if it cannot find the file with the exact path specified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's expecting you to use Apache's rewrite engine.  Did it come with a .htaccess file?  If so you'll need to set AllowOverride All in the VirtualHost or copy the contents of the file into the virtual host.